# Android: NoClassDefFoundError but doesn exist

Tags: android, android-intent, noclassdeffounderror

I have been updating an app that was released last year. when modifying the source code today on a completely different activity i noticed one of the activities, completely unrelated to what im working on had stopped working. Its giving me this error:

```
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/co/m/panic/MyLocationActivity
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at uk.co.m.panic.ParentActivity.onItemClick(ParentActivity.java:80)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1108)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:4760)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2571)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3284)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:195)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:315)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:58)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-08 13:59:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11526):    ... 15 more
```

usually NoClassDefError will be something like the activity is missing from the minfest. but in this case it isn't. The class names have not changed but i did update my v. of android sdk so i dont know if this has had involvement...

error happens on this line:

```
Intent myLocationItent = new Intent(ParentActivity.this, MyLocationActivity.class);
```

Comment: is your `MyLocationActivity` registered in `AndroidManifest` file??

Answer (score 0):

if you use `.jar` file, you have to add into `libs/` folder at the root of your project (next to `src/, res/,` etc.). Check this condition.